# How to compile & run programs written in T (a dialect of Lisp)

Tags: lisp, scheme, vax

I wanna compile and run a program written in the T programming language (a dialect of Lisp) during the years of 1980s. I checked the [T Project](http://mumble.net/~jar/tproject/) but it seems only applicable to VAX machines (and accompanied compilers)?

Are there any modern cmpilers for T? Or some modern dialect which is compatible?

Comment: Just "t" is going to make a horrible tag due to auto-complete shenanigans.  Perhaps `t-language` or `t-project` instead?

Answer (score 3):

This [page](http://web.archive.org/web/20070103020434/http://mumble.net/~campbell/t/t.html) lists the following platforms that T have been ported to:

- Ultrix (vax)
- Apollo Domain/OS (m68k)
- HP/UX (m68k)
- Mac/AUX (m68k)
- NeXT (m68k)
- SunOS 3 (m68k)
- SunOS 4 and above / Solaris (sparc)
- Encore Multimax (n32k)
- DEC3100 (pmax mips)
- SGI Iris (mips)
- Unix on the Connection Machine 5 (sparc)

The same page provides a Sparc image, so I'd look for a Sparc emulator.
For the latter take a look at: [Running Solaris Sparc software on X86-64](http://blog.boreas.ro/2008/03/runing-solaris-sparc-software-on-x86-64.html)

Also, I'd send a mail to the persons behind the T Revival project.

- Taylor R. Campbell: (format '#f "~A@~A.net" "campbell" "mumble")
- Brian Mastenbrook: (format '#f "~A@cs.~A.edu" "bmastenb" "indiana")

Comment: Thanks. I'll go for a Sparc emulator. But QuickTransit seems dead so maybe QEMU is a better choice? (I haven't used either..)

Comment: QEMU seems to be a good choice (I haven't tried to emulate a Sparc with it, but the docs say it is supported).

Comment: I just took a quick look at one of the tar files at the T page that soegaard mentioned.  It looks like the base system is written in C.  It might not be very big.  It's possible that it wouldn't be an incredible amount of trouble to port it to whatever system you're on, if you're comfortable with C enough to chase down the libraries and syntax differences causing errors.

Comment: @Mars AFAIK T3 is bootstrapped using T2, and the C part is for foreign language interface only. However it's somehow quite difficult to repeat the bootstrapping process.